# Struts 2 <s:if> tag issue

Tags: struts2, struts

I have a pojo class as below:

```
public class HelpBean {
 private String title;

 public String getTitle(){
  return title;
 }

 public void setTitle(String title){
  this.title = title;
 }

}
```

An action class as follows:

```
public class MyAction implements Action {
 private HelpBean bean;
 //other fields

 public HelpBean getBean() {
  return bean;
 }

 public void setBean(HelpBean bean) {
  this.bean = bean;
 }

}
```

In my jsp page, I am trying to check for below condition:

```
<s:if test=%{!bean.getTitle().trim().contains("bad_title")}>
    //execute good code
</s:if>
```

I also tried below, but this one also doesn't work:

```
<s:if test=%{bean.getTitle().trim().contains("bad_title") == false}>
    //execute good code
</s:if>
```

Not sharing the xml, as routing and everything works fine. I only have problem checking if my title does not contains "bad_title".

There are many different titles so I can't compare for `contains()` here, hence checking for `!contains()`

What am I missing here? Can someone pls point out. Before down voting, please explain if something is missed.

Comment: Have you checked what "bean.getTitle().trim()" actually returns?

Comment: Properties need to be quoted as Evgeni says.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the check should be

```
<s:if test="%{!bean.getTitle().trim().contains('bad_title')}">
```